# How to destroy dynamic component in angular after using it

Tags: angular

I am reusing a component that basically show a list of items in angular as a full screen searcher.

I can pass the items to be rendered: the item names, the type of the items and etc to render it on the screen for the user. After some time, i notice that the component is somehow "storing" the previous data inside the component, so if i call it again, the previous data is still being showed inside it and some of my data is async, so it take some time to be rendered totally to the user. That's why i came with this necessity of "destroying" it after each use.

```
<ng-container
  *ngIf="searcherOpen && meioAmeioOpen && optionsMeioAMeio.length > 0"
>
  <app-fullscreenSearcher
    [Items]="optionsMeioAMeio"
    Type="Cardapio"
    (arrowBtnAction)="setmeioAmeioClosed()"
    (saborSelectFn)="pushSabor($event)"
    inputPlaceHolder="Buscar itens, ingredientes, etc..."
  ></app-fullscreenSearcher>
</ng-container>
```

i'm just turning that "searcherOpen" boolean variable to show the fullscreenSearcher on the screen.

Inside my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-fullscreenSearcher",
  templateUrl: "./fullscreenSearcher.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./fullscreenSearcher.component.scss"],
})
export class FullscreenSearcherComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() inputPlaceHolder: string = new Input();
  @Input() Items: any[] = new Input();
  @Input() Type: string = new Input();
  @Input() Sabor: Produto = new Input();
  @Input() Tamanho = new Input();
  @Input() MeioAmeio: boolean = new Input();

  @Output() arrowBtnAction = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() saborSelectFn = new EventEmitter();

  public Theme: Temas = this.GlobalStorage.getStoreThemes();
  public Rgb;

  public CardapioArr;

  public AdicionaisArr: Adicionais[] = [];

  public filter:string = "";

  public AdicionalList:Adicionais[] = [];
  

  constructor(private GlobalStorage: GlobalStorage) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

    this.Rgb =
      "#" +
        this.Theme.Parametros.find(
          (param) => param.Chave == "MV_COLOR_BACKGROUND"
        ).Valor || "#940f11";

    if (this.Type == "Cardapio") {
      this.CardapioArr = this.FormatItemsIntoCategories(this.Items);

      console.log("Cardapio: ", this.CardapioArr);
    }

    if (this.Type == "Adicional") {
      this.AdicionaisArr = this.Sabor.Tamanhos.find(
        (tamanho) => tamanho.Codigo == this.Tamanho.Codigo
      ).Adicionais;
    }
  }

  EmitArrowBtnAction() {
    return this.arrowBtnAction.emit();
  }

  FormatItemsIntoCategories(Arr) {
    const _categories = [
      ...new Set(Arr.map((category) => category.DescricaoCategoria)),
    ];
    const arr: any = _categories.reduce((acc: any, category) => {
      const _categories = Arr.filter(
        (item: any) => item.DescricaoCategoria == category
      );

      return [...acc, { category: category, items: _categories }];
    }, []);

    return arr;
  }

  EmitSaborSelected(sabor) {
    this.saborSelectFn.emit(sabor);
  }

  ClearFilter(){
    return this.filter = "";
  }

  PushAdicionalArray(adcItem:Adicionais){
     this.AdicionaisArr.push(adcItem)
     console.log(this.AdicionaisArr);
  }
  RemoveAdicionalArray(adcItem:Adicionais, index){
    return this.AdicionaisArr.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

What is the best approach to solve this problem? It's this case actually a problem or i done something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to use `ngOnChanges` to trigger any events needed on that component.

There are a couple of triggers based on `this.Type`. To have them re-run, you could write something like this:

```
ngOnChanges( { Type }: SimpleChanges) {
  // Only run this if Type has changed
  if(Type) {
    if (this.Type == "Cardapio") {
      this.CardapioArr = this.FormatItemsIntoCategories(this.Items);

      console.log("Cardapio: ", this.CardapioArr);
    }

    if (this.Type == "Adicional") {
      this.AdicionaisArr = this.Sabor.Tamanhos.find(
        (tamanho) => tamanho.Codigo == this.Tamanho.Codigo
      ).Adicionais;
    }
  }
}
```

If that's not the issue, you could always create an `ngOnDestroy` function and add a `console.log` in there to see when the component actually destroys itself.

Comment: Above is a quick solution. After cleanup, the 2 conditionals would probably be in a separate private function

Comment: That means that the component will be re-render everytime the arg "Type" changes?

Comment: It'll only re-run what's inside of that `if(Type`) conditional again. You can always add more conditionals in there, this is just a starting point.